# Resharper automatically removes whitespace on run

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2017

I've been facing a weird problem in Resharper recently. When I make any bit of change on code and run, the whitespace after where the cursor is currently at are removed.

Here is an example:

```
public void Sample() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stackoverflow");
}
```

Just assume that the mouse cursor is placed at the 3rd line after the semicolon. When I click '**Run**', the code instantly gets reformatted and becomes like this:

```
public void Sample() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stackoverflow");}
```

I could not find anything in Options. I believe that this is not a formatting issue because, in the options panel, there is no setting indicating how to apply formatting on run.

Do you have any advice?

*(By the way, I am using a licensed Resharper Ultimate 2017.1 and Visual Studio  2017 Community)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found a solution. If you are a Resharper user and using DevExpress components in your project at the same time, **licenses.licx** file will probaby cause the problem I mentioned above. When you clear the contents of that file, the problem completely disappears.